# PyQGIS QgsMessageLog "NameError: name 'Qgis' is not defined"

Tags: pyqgis, debugging, qthread

I'm trying to debug a pyQGIS plugin, but can't get one of the Qthread working. I was told QgsMessageLog was the best way;

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage("before simplify", "plugin", level=Qgis.Info)
```

At best I get "NameError: name 'Qgis' is not defined", or nothing if I remove the last 1-2 arguments.

```
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
```

QGIS 3.2 on Win10 Pro...

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `Qgis`.

```
from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsMessageLog
QgsMessageLog.logMessage("before simplify", "plugin", level=Qgis.Info)
```

Comment: Of course... that said it still doesn't display anything. At least no error message, but even with a warning level, nada. And by now I just figured out that I just have to remove the Qthread to find the errors in 5 minutes, instead of spending hours trying to debug it without any indication...

Comment: QgsMessageLog adds a message in the QGIS logs, the small comic strip bubble in the right bottom corner.

Comment: Right, and usually the message automatically appears above the map, at least with my installation. Here nothing, even if I click on the bubble icon. And no exceptions/traceback... Apparently a problem with Qthread, I can only run smaller datasets with Qthread, it just freezes or crashes QGIS (faster than the same class/functions/code/data without it). Qthread also seems unstable, the same data set works one time, then the next day it crashes. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure what is your script. Instead of QThread, maybe use QgsTask and QgsTask.fromFunction ? Also, why are you on QGIS 3.2 ? or is it a typo 3.20 ?